# How to do a ManytoMany or ManyToOne Doctrine Neo4j

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, neo4j

I'm learning how to work with Neo4j and Doctrine OGM, and I'm having problems with my source code. I  don't know how to use manytomany because I'm just starting  learn. When I save I see:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Entity\Empresas::setTelefone() must be an instance of Entity\Entity\Telefones, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/neo4j/n4j/save.php on line 17 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/neo4j/n4j/Empresas.php on line 50

**My Empresas.php entity**

```
namespace Entity;

use HireVoice\Neo4j\Annotation as OGM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * All entity classes must be declared as such.
 *
 * @OGM\Entity(labels="Empresas")
 */
class Empresas
{
    /**
     * The internal node ID from Neo4j must be stored. Thus an Auto field is required
     * @OGM\Auto
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OGM\Property
     * @OGM\Index
     */
    protected $nome;

    /**
     * @OGM\Property
     */
    protected $keywords;

    /**
     * @OGM\ManyToOne(relation="tem_telefone")
     */
    protected $telefone;


    function getID(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    function setNome($nome){
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
     function setKeywords($keywords){
        $this->keywords = $keywords;
    }

    public function getTelefone() {
         return $this->telefone;
    }
    public function setTelefone(Entity\Telefones $telefone) {
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
    }
}`
```

**My Telefones.php Entity**

```
    <?php
namespace Entity;

use HireVoice\Neo4j\Annotation as OGM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * All entity classes must be declared as such.
 *
 * @OGM\Entity(labels="Empresas")
 */
class Telefones
{
    /**
     * The internal node ID from Neo4j must be stored. Thus an Auto field is required
     * @OGM\Auto
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OGM\Property
     * @OGM\Index
     */
    protected $telefone;



    function getID(){
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

**And my Save.php Entity**

```
    <?php

require 'bootstrap.php';
require 'Empresas.php';
require 'Telefones.php';

$repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\\Empresas');

$empresa_container = $em->find('Entity\\Empresas', "22");
$telefones = new Entity\Telefones();



$empresa = new Entity\Empresas;
$empresa->setNome("nome");
$empresa->setKeywords("keywords");
$empresa->setTelefone("telefone");

$em->persist($telefones);
$em->persist($empresa);
$em->flush();
echo $empresa->getId();
```

Error

Comment: The error is rather clear. Your `setTelefone()` method expects `Telefones` object, but instead of it you pass `"telefone"` string. Just pass your object: `$empresa->setTelefone($telefones);`

Comment: I'm trying to do this but up to now is not running. Do you can send source code for save?